# How can I set the timestamp on my datadog log?

Tags: datadog

Datadog is reporting the timestamp of my logs based on the arrival time at their server... how can I define the timestamp myself? I tried:

```
curl -X POST "https://http-intake.logs.datadoghq.com/api/v2/logs" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "DD-API-KEY: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" \
-d @- << EOF
{
  "ddsource": "dotnet",
  "ddtags": "env:stg,version:5.1,trace_id:2023097799433737367",
  "hostname": "Test Machine Leo",
  "message": "Teste Leo",
  "service": "srp_complementar-oracle",
  "trace_id": "2023097799433737367",
  "timestamp": "1678965326",
  "span_id": "1234"
}
EOF
```

but despite receiving a 202, the logs never show up

Answer (score 0):

```
  "timestamp": "2023-03-16T05:38:58.995Z",
```

the timestamp was in a incorrect format, and yes, you need the `Z`